# Refresh MS Access Query (VBA Code)

Tags: forms, ms-access, refresh, vba

I have a form in MS Access for which I am trying to have a refresh performed every time someone selects a project number from a combo box. Particularly the text fields on the form do not seem to refresh.

Is there any VBA code that can be used to perform this? Does the user have to click "next record"?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the data source of the form itself.  Set it to nothing and then set it to the appropriate query def.